# kpsewhich doesn't find package but should be as indicated by debug output

Tags: kpathsea, kpsewhich

currently I'm experimenting a bit with installing packages manually (not prepackaged from the repositories (I'm under Linux)). I use `tllocalmgr` (see [this wiki post here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live#tllocalmgr) and [this package here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tllocalmgr-git)), but I think this is not the point. In effect I have the (tex-) package installed at `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/`.

The problem I ran into is that `kpsewhich` seems not to be able to find the (tex-) package. What made me wonder was that when enabling the debug output, I can see that `kpsewhich` indeed looked into the `/usr/share/texmf-dist/` directory.

Can someone help me finding the issue here?

Note: I'm using ArchLinux (this is no I use Arch btw, but I think I read somewhere that arch does some things regarding some paths when compiling tex)

See my output on the console:

```bash
$ tllocalmgr install nicematrix && sudo texhash
Initializing ...
==> ERROR: PKGBUILD does not exist.
==> WARNING: A package has already been built, installing existing package...
==> Installing package texlive-local-nicematrix with pacman -U...
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) texlive-local-nicematrix-62660-1

Total Installed Size:  0,30 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                     [#####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                   [#####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                        [#####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                  [#####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                                [#####################################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) installing texlive-local-nicematrix                                                                          [#####################################################################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...

>>> Finished. Don't forget to run 'texhash' to update your file database.
texhash: Updating /etc/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Done.
$ pacman -Ql texlive-local-nicematrix
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/local/
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/local/share/
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/local/share/texmf/
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/nicematrix/
texlive-local-nicematrix /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty
$ kpsewhich tikz
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.tex
$ kpsewhich -debug=2 nicematrix
kdebug:db:init(): using db file /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R.
kdebug:db:init(): using db file /usr/share/texmf/ls-R.
kdebug:db:init(): using db file /etc/texmf/ls-R.
kdebug:db:init(): using db file /var/lib/texmf/ls-R.
kdebug:db:init(): using db file /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R.
kdebug:/usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R: 6 entries in 4 directories (0 hidden).
kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 6 nonempty (0%); 6 entries, average chain 1.0.
kdebug:/usr/share/texmf/ls-R: 20 entries in 7 directories (0 hidden).
kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 22 nonempty (0%); 26 entries, average chain 1.2.
kdebug:/etc/texmf/ls-R: 29 entries in 12 directories (0 hidden).
kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 46 nonempty (0%); 55 entries, average chain 1.2.
kdebug:/var/lib/texmf/ls-R: 149 entries in 28 directories (0 hidden).
kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 172 nonempty (0%); 204 entries, average chain 1.2.
kdebug:/usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R: 30102 entries in 2202 directories (0 hidden).
kdebug:ls-R hash table:64007 buckets, 20285 nonempty (31%); 30306 entries, average chain 1.5.
$ cat /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R
% ls-R -- filename database for kpathsea; do not change this line.
./:
.:
ls-R
tex


./tex:
latex

./tex/latex:
nicematrix

./tex/latex/nicematrix:
nicematrix.sty
$
```

Comment: Just tried compiling a sample tex document, this way the package is being found which I find kinda strange since I always thought `kpsewhich` would be the library tex uses internally to find the package files. But as this question doesn't really fit into this post, I'll create a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `kpsewhich nicematrix.sty` would have been able to find the file